# Memory test memtest86+ freezes after a short while

Tags: lubuntu, memory-test

On entering to memtest86+ the entire system freezes and there is no memory spd information given. Is it a memory failure and how can I solve it?

[image: THE WINDOW FREEZES FOR A LONG TIME]

Comment: Check your hardware. It is reliable tool.

Comment: How could I do that. Even if I get a hold of components how could I make sure it is the problem??

Answer (score 2):

There are reports of a bug in Memtest86+ 5.01 that causes freezes, usually in test 7. That said, there are also reports that it can also freeze in other tests on certain machines like ThinkPad Tx30. I have a ThinkPad T430s, which freezes no matter what RAM is installed when tested with Memtest86+ 5.01. Yet the same machine passes over and over with Memtest86+ 4.20 with the same RAM.